# NSDictionary not key value coding-compliant for the key Test

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

I'm trying to use `NSDictionary` in a way that I can store `NSArrays` in it, but I can't even get it working for strings.

```
_times = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *test = @"Test";
[_times setValue:@"testing" forKey:test];
NSLog(@"%@",[_times objectForKey:test]);
```

For the code above, I get the error message 
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x8b86540> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Test.'`

Why would an `NSString *` not work as a key? In fact, that's precisely what the method calls for.

Comment: Leaving my 5 cents here, in case someone was receiving this error when using 
`setValue:forKeyPath:` you should know that:

- even though your top dictionary object may be mutable (`NSMutableDictionary`),
- the one you're trying to reach by the `keyPath` may still be immutable (`NSDictionary`), 

and that does lead to the error above.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is immutable, so you can't set value to it.
use `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *times = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

I am including @Martin's comment here

In addition: Use `setObject:forKey` to set dictionary values. `setValue:forKey` is only needed for **"Key-Value Coding" magic**. `setObject:forKey` would also give a better error message if applied to an immutable dictionary.

Comment: @Inbl: In addition: Use `setObject:forKey` to set dictionary values. `setValue:forKey` is only needed for "Key-Value Coding magic". `setObject:forKey` would also give a better error message if applied to an immutable dictionary.

Comment: @Inbl This is certainly correct, though this doesn't fully address the original problem.  When you're using a dictionary, make sure you're calling `-setObject:forKey:` instead.  `-setValue:forKey:` is reserved for key-value coding, and using the former would have gotten you a compile-time error instead of a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Also, for dictionaries, KVC is an inefficient way to set key/value pairs. Better to use the NSMutableDictionary method setObject:forKey: